# Best way to reuse code at unit testing in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, code-reuse

I'm using buster.js as the test runner. The basic test is something like:

```
// Test globals
var var1='foo1', var2='foo2';

// Test run
describe('Description', function(){
    beforeEach(){
        console.log('var2');
    }
    it('should ....', function(){
        expect(var1).toEqual('foo1');
    }
});
```

Now, imagine I have another test that needs to use the same beforeEach, plus anything else, and the same it, plus anything else.

What would be the best approach to reuse this code in JavaScript? specially in buster.js or mocha?.

Comment: So basically, you want to use it something like a template right?

Comment: Yes I guess, some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Its some sort of context that you need to create and encapsulate it as a class .

```
class TestContext {
   this.var1 = undefined
   this.var2 = undefined

   buildUp(next) {
         // do whatever init you need
        next && next()
   }

  tearDown(next) {
        //clean up stuff
        next && next()
  }

  get sharedTestSteps() {
     return [
        {
            text: "it should something", 
            fn: next => { //...do some testing   }
        }
     ]
  }
}
```

The test looks like that:

```
describe("...", () => {

   var c = new TextContext()

   before(next => c.buildUp(next))

   after( () => c.tearDown())

   it("should work", () => {
        //work with c.var1
   })

  c.sharedSteps.forEach({text, fn} =>  it(text, fn))
})
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, but I don't really understand the '=>' parts and the 'next && next()' parts, is it ES 6?

Comment: looks like `C#'`s`linq` to me

Comment: The `=>` is called the [fat] arrow function operator.  It is a shorthand function definition (with a lexically scoped `this`): `a => b` is `function(a){return(b);}`

Comment: And `next && next();` is `if (next != null) next();`  That is, if next points to something (presumably a function) then call that function.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using Template Design Pattern

I would do something like this

```
function TestModule(description){

  this.stages = [];
  this.description = description;
  this.stage = function(name, fn){

    this.stages.push({
      name: name,
      fn: fn
    });

  };

  this.execute = function(){

    describe(this.description, function(){

      //here comes your template
      //this is the part where you define your template
      beforeEach(this.stages[0].fn);
      it(this.stages[1].name, this.stages[1].fn);
      it(this.stages[2].name, this.stages[2].fn);


    });

  };

}


//now this is how you'll use it
var mod = new TestModule('Module description here');

mod.stage('Before each', function(){
  //before each here
});
mod.stage('Should do something', function(){
  //test here
});

mod.execute();

/////////////////////////

//another module

var mod2 = new TestModule('Module description here');

mod2.stage('Before each', function(){
  //before each here
});
mod2.stage('Should do something', function(){
  //test here
});

mod2.execute();
```

now we can actually go further, making this Class' template customizable as well.